# How to create two query mysql insert and create table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I would like to create two queries, one to enter the data into one table, another to create a new table. This is my code that creates the new table but does not insert the data. Where am I wrong? Thank you.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO progetti(data, ora, nome_progetto)VALUES('".$_POST["data"]."','".$_POST["ora"]."','".$_POST["nome_progetto"]."')";

          "CREATE TABLE $_POST[nome_progetto] (
            id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            data date,
            intervento varchar(30),
            descrizione varchar(70),
            ore int(2)
          )";
```

Comment: PHP doesn't support multi queries. Btw, please learn about SQL injection and how to prevent them @ http://bobby-tables.com ... your code is not safe at all and your database could be hacked in a few seconds. Please use prepared statements for user inputs in queries.

Comment: You need to separate the two `SQL` statements.

Comment: @Twinfriends see [mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can create if else statement , if insertion is done then creation will run

```
<?php

/*
* These are Database Credentials
*/
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = " ";
    $dbname = "test_db";

    /*
    * Intiating the Database connection
    */
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    /*
    * Checking the Databse connection
    */
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

     $create = "CREATE TABLE ".$_POST[nome_progetto]." (
                    id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    data date,
                    intervento varchar(30),
                    descrizione varchar(70),
                    ore int(2))";
            $result = $conn->query($create);     

    if ($result === TRUE) {
     $sql = "INSERT INTO progetti(data, ora, nome_progetto)VALUES('".$_POST["data"]."','".$_POST["ora"]."','".$_POST["nome_progetto"]."')";

      $insert = $conn->query($sql); 
      if ($insert === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    }


    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, query does not work, you put the full code. The application is installed on a local PC and not connected to the Internet. I'm new to php and some syntax I'm unknown.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO progetti
       (data, ora)
       VALUES
       ('".$_POST["data"]."',
       '".$_POST["ora"]."',
       )";
       $query = $conn->query($sql);
            $result = $query->result();
       if(isset($result)){
              $sql = "CREATE TABLE $_POST[nome_progetto] (
                id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                data date,
                intervento varchar(30),
              )";
              $query = $conn->query($sql);
              $query->result();
            }

Comment: Hi Max Don't Worry man,
Initially, You should install the wamp server in your local system
Then there is a folder in C:/ Wamp64/www
create file with some sample.php and  paste that Code
Update the credentials of database in code
Then you have to pass the Post values
Check it out
i have modified  the answer

Comment: Hi, now everything works perfectly! Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use different SQL statement ( in your case 2, one for insert and other one for create table )
2. use prepare statements provided by Abstraction Layers ( PDO )  in PHP
3. read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)